# How to clear ionic tab history?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new in Ionic framework. I was trying to list some data in ionic tabs using ng-repeat. I used a filter to differentiate what is to be listed in tabs.

My HTML:

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-top tab-section">

  <!-- Daily Tab -->
  <ion-tab title="Daily Task"  href="">
    <div class="list tasks-wrapper" id="daily">
        <div class="item item-avatar item-icon-right tasks-listing" ng-repeat="task in tasks | filter: dateRangeFilter('daily')">
             <a ng-href="#/details/{{task.Id}}">
                  <h2 ng-bind="task.TaskName"></h2>                
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
  </ion-tab>

  <!-- Weekly Tab -->
  <ion-tab title="Weekly Task"  href="">
    <div class="list tasks-wrapper" id="weekly">
       <div class="item item-avatar item-icon-right tasks-listing" ng-repeat="task in tasks | filter: dateRangeFilter('weekly')">
             <a ng-href="#/details/{{task.Id}}">
                  <h2 ng-bind="task.TaskName"></h2>
            </a>
        </div>
     </div>
  </ion-tab>

</ion-tabs>
```

The Daily Tab contains the list of task for the current day, and the Weekly Tab contains the list of task for the entire week(including current days task). At first Daily Tab is displayed. But after loading Weekly Tab data the Daily Tab also display the Weekly Tab data. Its not getting updated.  What are the mistakes I made here?

**Daily Tab when first loaded**
[image: Daily Tab on the first loading]

**Weekly Tab when first loaded**
[image: Weekly Tab on the first loading]

**Daily Tab after loading Weekly Tab**
[image]

Comment: what do you mean by "the data is not changing for the first"? Is the tasks array modified in any way after its initialisation? when you change tabs? If the array is not modified, the lists won't change.

Comment: @Kaddath Thanks for replying. The question is edited.

Comment: can u provide codepen with this

Comment: oh i see, you mean the display is not updated to show daily tab content again? Maybe you can try to add a fixed debug text to each tab content? This will show if it is the tab content display that is not updated, (text won't change) of if the problem comes from injecting list values (text would change, but not the list)

Comment: Hey @ArjunAjith did you ever find a solution to this? I am having the same exact problem.